# How to wrap a number into a range?

Tags: c++

I have a program that takes every char in a string. adds a number x to it (x increases every time it adds to the char). I need the new character (c+x) to be withing the range [32,126].

I know to use %126 to keep the c+x<126, but how do I assure that c+x is also >32 and that the numbers are "wrapping" through that range?

Here is the code I have:

```
string a;
unsigned int x = 1;

cin >> a;

for (auto &c : a)
{
    if (c <= 126 && c >= 32)
    {
        if (c + x > 126) //checking if c needs to be wrapped
        {
            c = (c + x) % (126); //wrapping c? <-- this is the problem
        }
        else
        {
            c += x;
        }

        if (x == 256)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
    cout << c;
}
```

Edit: I figured it out the line to wrap it should be:

```
c = 31 + (c + x) % (126);
```

I realized I had tried this but with 32 instead of 31, and that means it would exclude it from wrapping into 32.

Comment: Did you lose `int main()` at the top of your code (and some `#include` directives), or was this a fragment of something larger?  (I don't want to edit to "correct" if there was more to it than that.

Comment: Your edit does not look as though it uses a correct formula.  Since the number should be in the range 32..126 (including both end values), you need to work modulo (126-32+1 = 95).  As shown, you could end up with 31 (if c+x is a multiple of 126), or you could end up with 156 (if c+x % 126 is 125).  Neither meets the criteria you set out.  The answer is more precise.

Answer (score 12):

UPD: please, see @Ky's comment below, I'll update the answer a bit later.

Since `%` operator lets you to get a `[0; limit)` space, a standard approach when you need a `[start; limit)` space is to get a space `[0; limit - start]` via `%` operator and then add it to `start`. This way you'll get a `[start; limit)` space. So the formula would be

`numberToBeWrapped = start + (numberToBeWrapped - start) % (limit - start)`

Or, in your case:

`c = 32 + (c + x - 32) % (126 - 32);`

Comment: For some reason that did not give me the right outcome. the input "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" should become "bdfhjlnprtvxz|~!#%')+-/1"

Comment: @TimothyColemanHarrelson, yes, sorry, there was a mistake: you should also subtract `start` from the `numberToBeWrapped`. I fixed the formula as well as the code for your case.

Comment: I got it, the number at the start had to be start-1 or it excludes the starting number from being wrapped into.

Comment: @TimothyColemanHarrelson, I'm glad, that you found a way to make it work :) One note: I've just noticed, that you use `% 126` instead of `% 127`. `% 126` will give you the range `[0; 125]` (126 is not included).

Comment: This fails if `numberToBeWrapped` is less than `start` (e.g. `wrap(n: 2, start: 3, limit: 5) == 2` when it should be `4`)

Comment: @Ky., indeed, you're right! My mistake. I'll update the answer a bit later, for now I added a warning about it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
int wrapSpaceSingle(int start, int end, int wrapNum) {
    int out = ((wrapNum % (end - start)) + (end - start)) % (end - start) + start;
    return out;
}
```

That should work.